How to escape backticks in FreeBSD
This is on csh (FreeBSD):
echo "complete service 'c/-/(e l r v)/' 'p/1/`service -l`/' 'n/*/(start stop reload restart status rcvar onestart onestop)/'" >> /root/.cshrc

I want to use this in my install script, but when I run this command then "service -l" is run and the output included into /root/.cshrc.
I tried all kinds of escaping, all kinds of combinations of ' ", I even tried $() but absolutely nothing works for me.
